# How to achieve a realistic neumorphism raised text effect in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, typography

How do I create a raised text effect similar to this photo in photoshop?:

[image]

I've tried using a few of the different bevel effects but nothing comes close to looking that realistic. I think this may be a photo of something that was actually printed, but is there any way to replicate the same look in photoshop?

Comment: Looks like a 3D text to me. And I don't know why I feel similar have been asked a few months ago.

Comment: Anyone else remember?

Comment: @curious, sure it's not post-neomorphism 2.0? 

Comment: @Wolff I'm trying to make it more precise than simply "raised text" ^^

Answer (score 2):

I feel similar question has been asked before, but I couldn't find it. I'm writing an answer any way:

1. Create a text layer and apply a thin inner Bevel like this (Uncheck global light). Choose bright and dark green colors for highlights and shadow. Let's call it Layer 1.

[image]

2. Duplicate the layer and press <kbd>Cntl</kbd> + Click to make a selection of text. Contract the selection a bit by `Select > Modify > Contract` and then create a new solid layer with same fill color as text. Let's call it Layer 2 and it should be on to of Layer 1
3. Apply the same Bevel to it, but increase the size a bit.

   Infact, experiment with the sizes of both of Layers' Bevels. You'll
   notice that you can get similar effect when you change settings like
   size and technique of Bevel (Chisel hard/soft) and colors of
   highlights/shadows.

[image]

4. Group both layers and convert to smart object and then apply a bright shadow in top right side of group and dark green shadow in bottom left side. Create layer styles (`Layer > Layer Style > Create Layer`) from the effects and mask unnecessary shadows if you have to.

[image]

[image]

Layer panel screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Note: In the step 2, when you create selection and contract it, some of the corners of the font can become a bit round. If you want, you can fix it by manually fixing the masked area and making those corners sharp.